# How to release NSTimer? or stop timer. Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

After the end of our game the NSTimer does not stop.

```
-(void)StartGame{
Countdown = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(TimeDecrease) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)TimeDecrease{
    StartTime = StartTime - 1;
    Timer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",StartTime];
    if(StartTime == 0){
        [self EndGame];
    }
}
```

We tried [Countdown release] and disabled ARC but it throws an error. 
We are trying to accomplish a timer that resets to 15 at the beginning of every new game.

Comment: Read the docs for `NSTimer`. There is a clear, specific method for stopping the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
[Countdown invalidate];
Countdown = nil;
```

Comment: Now it is starting at 0 on the second game but then quickly jumps to 14. I want it to start directly at 15.

Comment: You should be able to just create a new `NSTimer` with the timeout you want.